# Does Symfony automatically gets foreign key value into database through entity references?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product" , fetch="EAGER", inversedBy="MarketingUrls")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $Product;
```

I want to understand what does this means in symfony framework. I am trying to insert foreign key value into database for that I have written above piece of code but it is not working. Should I manually insert value using form or it will automatically takes it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also have a OneToMany annotation on the other entity (Product).
By using a form (and adding an 'entity' field for your product), Symfony should take care of inserting the foreign key in your MarketingUrl entity.